# How do I ask users to enter the name of EXCEL file in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, input, messagebox, matlab-guide

I am using MATLAB R2010b. I am doing clustering with k-means algorithm. And everytime it is executed, it always shows different result. And I want it to be saved, always, in Excel.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
y = [data x];
xlswrite('clustering.xls', y, 'KMEANS', 'A1');
```

As I said before; everytime it is executed, it shows different result, so the clustering.xls is always updated, updated, and updated--without saving the old file. I want to save all the history. The only thing I think that can be solved this problem, is users rename their own file--but it is not efficient. So, I think I need a messagebox to let user enter the name of their xls file.

How to make it possible? Any idea?

I appreciate all the answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the input function:

```
y = [data x];
xlsFileName = input('Enter the name for the xls file: ', 's');
xlswrite(xlsFileName, y, 'KMEANS', 'A1');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is simple and so much easier. Going to tyr this. :)

Answer (score 4):

It would seems like you might find `uiputfile` useful for your task.
see doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiputfile.html

Comment: Thank you, Shai, for the answer, but uigetfile is simply not what I am looking for. It is used to import file. In this case, I want to **export** the file into excel. I have did it clearly (look at the snippet code), but I want to ask users to input the name of their own excel before it is exported.

Comment: @AlviSyahrin have you considered `uiputfile` that I mensioned?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a slightly different alternative, i.e. to write each set of results to a separate **sheet** in excel by changing the 3rd input.

The following loop demonstrates a basic example:

```
for ii = 1:10
    xlswrite('test.xlsx',rand(10),ii)
end
```

You will find out that he sheets are named `sheet1, sheet2,...`

You can also suppress the warning about the creation of new sheets with:

```
warning('off','MATLAB:xlswrite:AddSheet')
```

Comment: +1 especially, if the OP wants to save *all* the history, continuously entering file names can become tedious.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative idea! I think this is going to be more efficient. :)